# using a draggable as a source list links items added to a sortable together?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-sortable

excuse the hacked together sample

http://jsfiddle.net/marcmeans/SqrBf/1/

If you add an item from the available students to Table3 twice and then try and move one from Table3 to Table2, both disappear.

I note as well that when I'm generating a new guid for the item added to Table3, the arg.item seems be a reference to the item in the source list and not  a clone.  This creates a link in knockout where if I update one I update them all.

I'm assuming that I am doing something wrong here, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what.

Comment: 1) your code is not OOP in any real sense 2) your UI seems flawed in that you're adding the same student to multiple tables 3) you don't seem to have any direct way of managing the students & table information in your model.  I'd love to answer your question, but it's not a "single answer" type of question.  There's too much wrong to analyze it in a brief enough time period for me to have the energy to do it on top of everything else i have.  Sorry, @Marc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `draggable` functionality in the `sortable` plugin currently checks to see if your object has a `clone` function on it.  If it does, then it uses the result of calling `clone` as the new item.  If not, then it uses the item itself.

In your fiddle, you are using the mapping plugin, so one option would be to pass mapping options that customize how your students are getting created by adding a `clone` method.

Here is an updated fiddle that  passes the mapping options and clones the object just by doing `ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(this))`

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/SqrBf/3/

Comment: Thank you tons.  Exactly the problem I was having.