# knockout draggable sortable mapping clone alteration

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-sortable

I am trying to use knockout-sortable, with the mapping plugin, to drag a list of products to another list.

Here is a very [stripped-back fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cheersphilip/g5Lke4dw/1/) to try and show what I'm getting at.

What I want is for the products in the 'cart' to reference, not clone, the products on the 'shelf'.

I have managed to calculate the name of the items in the cart by referencing those on the shelf, but I am having trouble in getting the products in the cart to only have the data they need to make this reference, without all the other cruft.

Having looked around, I found this very tantalising solution by Ryan Niemeyer to a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517273/using-a-draggable-as-a-source-list-links-items-added-to-a-sortable-together) a couple of years ago, but the fiddles throw a 404 error!

I have created a 'clone' function, but because all my data is mapped it has not used a constructor such as:

```
var product = function(ID, name, other){
    this.productID = ko.observable(ID);
    //etc.
};
```

Which means that I cannot do what I want to do, which is:

```
product.prototype.clone = function(){
    var x = ko.mapping.toJS(this);
    delete x.productName; 
    delete x.someOtherData;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(x);
};
```

Which I would hope would drop a new object into the cart with just a reference to the original `productID` key. I have commented out the code for this in the fiddle. The `console.log` does not get called after dragging, so the function is not even getting called.

I also looked on the Google forum for knockout-sortable and found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/Ct8qwJvUsOA), which is where I got the clone bit from - but I can't make it fit my use case!

The result of a successful answer to this question will, when there is just a bike in the cart, leave `productArray` as it is and have `listArray` set to `[{'productID':1}]`.

This is the first time that I've posted a question on SO, so please go easy on me if I have not made myself clear! I am already indebted to the community, as it has been so helpful in solving my problems for years and years :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want your mapping options to look something like:

```
var options = {
    productArray: {
        create: function(mappingData) {
            var result = ko.mapping.fromJS(mappingData.data);

            result.clone = function() {
                return { productID: result.productID() };
            };

            return result;
        }
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you could create a constructor for your product with a clone function on it and just return that like `return new Product(mappingData.data);`

I had the clone above just return the productID as a non-observable, which should be fine unless you need to react to that value changing.

The first line of your `calculatedName` function would then need to be something like:

var x = ko.unwrap(arg.productID);

This will retrieve the value whether it is observable or not, so the function can work against the productArray or the listArray.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/hLqctg4L/

Comment: That non-observable clone has done the trick! In my application I need to have more than one list, and your solution also copes well with that: http://jsfiddle.net/cheersphilip/hLqctg4L/2/